# How i can use a static field to keep track of how many objects have been created from a particular class

Tags: c#

iam using c# and have a question,how the static field is used to count the number of instances in a class,please calrify in terms of memory,thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because "please calrify in terms of memory" is unclear. Also, having the proper spelling, capitalization and punctuation marks would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a counter to the constructor of your class

```
class MyClass
{

    static int instanceCount = 0;

    public MyClass()
    {
        instanceCount++;
    }

}
```

The constructor runs every time an instance of the class is created. The static variable is shared by all instances of the created class.

Comment: Granted the OP's question wasn't well formed, but what about when they are destroyed?

Answer (score 2):

To simply count the number of *constructions*, declare a static field and use `Interlocked.Increment` in your [instance constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx) to increment the static field in a thread-safe manner.

If you want to count *live objects*, you'll also need to `Interlocked.Decrement` that field in your finalizer (i.e. [C# destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)). Note, however, that adding a finalizer will make objects go through the finalization queue, making the garbage collection [less efficient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/20/77460.aspx).

Depending on how you define "live" object, you might alternatively be interested in adding `Interlocked.Decrement` in your `IDisposable.Dispose` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a constructor and destructor to achieve what you want, but you shouldn't really need to know how many instances of your class exist at any one time. It sounds like you're going about a problem in the wrong way.

```
class MyClass
{
    static int instances = 0;

    public MyClass()
    {
        instances++;
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        instances--;
    }
}
```

Note that a class's destructor won't be called immediately. It is up to the garbage collector to decide when it collects an instance of your class, and therefore when your destructor is called.

Comment: you seems to be didn't understand me,i want to know how this is handeled in memory but thanks any way for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
class someclass
{
    private static int instanceCounter;

    public someclass() { someclass.instanceCounter++; }
}
```

Comment: Hmm well you don't really have the concept of destructors in .Net, so I'm not 100% sure how to track that, without an explicate COM style AddRef/RemoveRef.